# Manipulating dataframe without for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I wrote a for loop to manipulate a rather large (~1,000,000 rows) dataframe but it runs far too slow and I couldn't find anything online.

```
df=data.frame(v1=runif(10), v2=runif(10), v3=runif(10), v4=0, v5=0, v6=0, v7=0)
for( i in 1:dim(df)[1] ) {
    df[i,4]=length(which(df[i,1:3]>0.00 & df[i,1:3]<0.10))
    df[i,5]=length(which(df[i,1:3]>0.10 & df[i,1:3]<0.50))
    df[i,6]=length(which(df[i,1:3]>0.50 & df[i,1:3]<0.90))
    df[i,7]=length(which(df[i,1:3]>0.90 & df[i,1:3]<1.00))
}
```

I've tried to write a function to do this, but it adds all row together:

```
test.fun <- function (df) {
    df[,4]=length(which(df[,1:3]>0.00 & df[,1:3]<0.10))
    df[,5]=length(which(df[,1:3]>0.10 & df[,1:3]<0.50))
    df[,6]=length(which(df[,1:3]>0.50 & df[,1:3]<0.90))
    df[,7]=length(which(df[,1:3]>0.90 & df[,1:3]<1.00))
    return(df)
}
 (test <- test.fun(df))
```

Comment: This isn't making sense to me. The length of these will be single numbers but you are assigning to an entire column. Rather than using failed code to communicate, I suggest you use natural language and pecify what form the answer shoiuld be returned in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***`rowSums`*** with the condition that you want is the main idea.

You can use ***`dplyr` package*** to make it cleaner:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(v4 = rowSums(df[,1:3]>0.00 & df[,1:3]<0.10))%>% 
 mutate(v5 = rowSums(df[,1:3]>0.10 & df[,1:3]<0.50))%>% 
 mutate(v6 = rowSums(df[,1:3]>0.50 & df[,1:3]<0.90))%>% 
 mutate(v7 = rowSums(df[,1:3]>0.90 & df[,1:3]<1.00))


#           v1         v2        v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 
# 1  0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393  0  1  1  1 
# 2  0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034  0  1  2  0 
# 3  0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068  0  1  2  0 
# 4  0.8830174 0.57263340 0.9942698  0  0  2  1 
# 5  0.9404673 0.10292468 0.6557058  0  1  1  1 
# 6  0.0455565 0.89982497 0.7085305  1  0  2  0 
# 7  0.5281055 0.24608773 0.5440660  0  1  2  0 
# 8  0.8924190 0.04205953 0.5941420  1  0  2  0 
# 9  0.5514350 0.32792072 0.2891597  0  2  1  0 
# 10 0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136  0  2  0  1
```

***Data:***

```
set.seed(123) #to make a reproducible example
df=data.frame(v1=runif(10), v2=runif(10), v3=runif(10), v4=0, v5=0, v6=0, v7=0)
```

Comment: For more efficiency compute the `rowSums` once at the top and assign it to a new variable, then use that for the comparisons instead of re-computing the sum for each added column.